# How to add styling to a JSX after its creation in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have a JSX element which is returned from some hidden source, lets assume for instance that the hidden source returns JSX like this:

```js
getElement = () => {
  return (<h1>Some Test </h1>)
}
```

and I store that JSX in some variable, e.g.

```
this.h = this.getElement()
```

How can I change the style of `h` before finally rendering it to the DOM without adding external CSS?

Comment: The answers below would work fine. But just to add this, you can use `React.cloneElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you write `from a hidden source` I assume you can not change the element (black box)

What you can do is change the style props of `h`:

```
this.h = this.getElement()
this.h.props.style = { ...this.h.props.style, { backgroundColor: "#00ff00" } }
```

[Here's an example, just using React Native, but same principle](https://snack.expo.io/@attaque/f37b47)

---

*How to figure it out:*

Inspecting the output of `getElement` with `console.log(getElement)` would show you that `<h1>` is transpiled into `React.createElement(...)` and `console.log(getElement())` would show you the returned object, where you can inspect `props.style`